# the correct way to "cross-post"?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, migration, math-stackexchange, cross-posting

Obviously is to not cross-post at all.  If I asked a question on Math.SE the crickets chirp, how do I move it to MO?  Or rephrase in an acceptable way?

I think we've all done it one or twice asked a question that is better suited in a different forum.  I don't have the authority to migrate my own questions.  How can I remedy this type of situation?

Comment: I don't get what is meant by "crickets chirp".

Comment: @Sanath: Google Is Your Friend.

Comment: Generally speaking I think it is better to avoid  figurative idioms here.

Comment: @quid: Can we still use colloquial metaphors? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila "avoid" was a bit strong, but I think the key point of a post should not depend on it. But, what actualluy made me write my comment, is first an foremost that OP independent of that is *quite* sloppily written: the strange start of body; the "Or rephrase in an acceptable way?" here, there, what does this mean exactly. And, second your somewhat dismissive comment: lmgtfy got band for a reason on SO.

Comment: @quid: I don't have a user account on SO, so it is impossible that I have posted that comment there.

Comment: @Asaf not sure there is a confusion but in case:  linking to the service lmgtfy is banned on SO as it happened so often (maybe the entire network even) [as opposed to somebody named lmgtfy getting banned over something]

Comment: @quid: I think that between the two of us, I managed to confuse you with my last comment, and not vice versa. :-)

Comment: @Asaf: okay, yes, I meant to use a semi-colon instead of a colon. (But "on SO" would then be part of the alledged comment so that you pointing out not having an account on SO is not really pertinent.) As usual, an amusing exchange, but I need to leave now. :-)

Comment: Timing:  Wait two weeks before concluding "there are no answers".

Comment: I agree that to wait a bit can make sense. But, two weeks seems way too long.

Comment: Some relevant discussions at meta.MSE: [Cross posting, or flag for migration?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10265/cross-posting-or-flag-for-migration) and [Moderator Supported (Official) Guidelines for “Legitimate” CrossPosting?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting).

Comment: I suggest reading Martin's linked items.  In particular, lack of feedback at MSE is not a good reason for posting on MO.  You really should consider whether or not the question is suitable for MO as the primary criterion for posting on MO.

Comment: @quid Honestly, I think you are being too harsh on the OP. You of all people ought to be careful about calling people out on their sloppy language; I have trouble parsing most of the things you write (your comments above are no exception). To return to the query: I second what Ryan said. "Rephrase in an acceptable way" (i.e., acceptable for MO) is a slightly loaded phrase.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I *do* realise this. However, if I ask a question it is typically not as sloppy as some other things I write. And, the point stands. The question would be  better if the lack of feedback was quantified explicitly. Furthermore, the body of a question should not depend on the title, especially not in such a convoluted way. Finally, we can decide to change the board to my native language, then I will make an effort to write in exemplary language.

Comment: @quid Your last comment was very well written (some users would be better off writing in their native language, but you are not among them). :-) I thought the OP was tolerably clear, if colloquially written: "crickets chirp" normally means dead silence from the audience. That can be taken to mean at a minimum that no one answered (would that be enough quantification?), and I would certainly interpret it also as saying that there were no comments, if that matters. I think I disagree it was very convoluted (I could follow it anyway), but I take your general point: clarity is always desirable.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thanks for the explanation and the compliment. What could be relevant in addition is the time that elapsed without feedback. But, in the end I have to agree that my contribution to this thread was unfortunately not really constructive. I caught myself in an unfortunate dynamic (inspecting the answer with your 'magic powers' will reveal still more); some of what I wrote is likely overly harsh.

Comment: @quid: Magical diamond powers? Sounds like a combination of Tolkien, Captain Planet, Futurama "The Mutants Are Revolting", and engagement rings in American-influenced societies.

Answer (score 12):

You can flag the post for moderator attention on MSE, choose the free-form flag and ask for a migration to MO.

Another option, which is useful when the crickets really chirp, and you haven't got any comments either, is to simply delete the question and post it anew on MO.